# How to execute actions when multiple check boxes selected?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcheckbox

When the user selects the multiple check boxes I need to execute the following with the same name. How to use the for loop condition for this?

I tried to use the if-else if but only one selection gets executed. Is there any way to implement for loop to reduce the code length?

I am using `JFrame` absolute layout so the checkbox variables already get pre-defined. I can't able to use an array.

```
public first() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 512, 263);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    
    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Checkout Suite:");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 11, 104, 20);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);
    
    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
    comboBox.addItem("Platform - Desktop");
    comboBox.addItem("Platform - Mobile");
    comboBox.setBounds(124, 11, 331, 20);
    contentPane.add(comboBox);          
    
    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Locales:");
    lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(10, 53, 79, 34);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);
    
    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox = new JCheckBox("A");
    chckbxNewCheckBox.setBounds(17, 94, 63, 23);
    contentPane.add(chckbxNewCheckBox);
    
    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_1 = new JCheckBox("B");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_1.setBounds(104, 94, 63, 23);
    contentPane.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_1);
    
    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_2 = new JCheckBox("C");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_2.setBounds(177, 94, 72, 23);
    contentPane.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_2);
    
    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_3 = new JCheckBox("D");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_3.setBounds(17, 133, 63, 23);
    contentPane.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_3);
    
    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_4 = new JCheckBox("E");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_4.setBounds(104, 133, 63, 23);
    contentPane.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_4);
    
    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_5 = new JCheckBox("F");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_5.setBounds(177, 133, 72, 23);
    contentPane.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_5);
    
    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_6 = new JCheckBox("G");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_6.setBounds(17, 174, 63, 23);
    contentPane.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_6);
    
    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_7 = new JCheckBox("H");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_7.setBounds(104, 174, 63, 23);
    contentPane.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_7);
    
    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_8 = new JCheckBox("I");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_8.setBounds(177, 174, 72, 23);
    contentPane.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_8);
    
    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Create Test Run");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            
            
            if(comboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("PLatform - Desktop"))
            {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
                WebDriver aru=new ChromeDriver();
                aru.manage().window().maximize();
                aru.get("https://google.com");
                
                //Testrail Login
                aru.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys("gmail@gmail.com");
                aru.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("xyz");
                aru.findElement(By.id("button_primary")).click(); //Login
                
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
                aru.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"suite-22496\"]/div[2]/div[1]/a")).click();
                aru.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"content-header\"]/div/div[2]/a[1]")).click();
                aru.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"includeSpecific\"]")).click();
                aru.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"includeSpecificInfo\"]/a")).click();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            
                aru.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"selectCasesNode-744350\"]/input")).click();
                aru.findElement(By.id("selectCasesSubmit")).click();
                
                //Suite Name
                aru.findElement(By.id("name")).clear();
                DateFormat today = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy ");
                Date palani = new Date();
                String content= today.format(palani);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
                if(chckbxNewCheckBox.isSelected())
                {
                    
                    aru.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys("Platform - Desktop - A - "+content);
                    //aru.findElement(By.className("button button-left button-positive button-ok")).click();
                    
                }
                
                else if(chckbxNewCheckBox_1.isSelected())
                {
                    aru.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys("Platform - Desktop - B - "+content);
                    //aru.findElement(By.className("button button-left button-positive button-ok")).click();
                }
                
                else if(chckbxNewCheckBox_2.isSelected())
                {
                    aru.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys("Platform - Desktop - C - "+content);
                    //aru.findElement(By.className("button button-left button-positive button-ok")).click();
                }
                else if(chckbxNewCheckBox_3.isSelected())
                {
                    aru.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys("Platform - Desktop - D - "+content);
                    //aru.findElement(By.className("button button-left button-positive button-ok")).click();
                }
                
                else if(chckbxNewCheckBox_4.isSelected())
                {
                    aru.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys("Platform - Desktop - E - "+content);
                    //aru.findElement(By.className("button button-left button-positive button-ok")).click();
                }
                else if(chckbxNewCheckBox_5.isSelected())
                {
                    aru.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys("Platform - Desktop - F - "+content);
                    //aru.findElement(By.className("button button-left button-positive button-ok")).click();
                }
                else if(chckbxNewCheckBox_6.isSelected())
                {
                    aru.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys("Platform - Desktop - G - "+content);
                    //aru.findElement(By.className("button button-left button-positive button-ok")).click();
                }
                else if(chckbxNewCheckBox_7.isSelected())
                {
                    aru.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys("Platform - Desktop - H - "+content);
                    //aru.findElement(By.className("button button-left button-positive button-ok")).click();
                }
                else if(chckbxNewCheckBox_8.isSelected())
                {
                    aru.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys("Platform - Desktop - I - "+content);
                    //aru.findElement(By.className("button button-left button-positive button-ok")).click();
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select from list");
                }
                
            }
                
            
        }
    });
    
    btnNewButton.setBounds(285, 122, 169, 34);
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
}
}
```

Comment: Do not use `else if`. Just use several `if`.

Comment: what I have to return in else statement?

Comment: Nothing. You have checkboxes and you want to make the logic associated with your check-boxes to be executed. That means you could have several check-boxes enabled. If you use `if` without else then all mathced `if`s will be sequentially executed. If you use `else` with `if`, then you will **either** execute code block under `if` **or** code block under `else`. But never both.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 0):

If you use `else if` it will stop executing further cases as soon as one `if` returns true. One way to maybe reduce your code a bit would be by adding all the Checkboxes to an `ArrayList` and then loop through that.

```java
    List<JCheckBox> cbList = new ArrayList<>();

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox = new JCheckBox("US");
    chckbxNewCheckBox.setBounds(17, 94, 63, 23);
    contentPane.add(chckbxNewCheckBox);
    cbList.add(chckbxNewCheckBox);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_1 = new JCheckBox("UK");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_1.setBounds(104, 94, 63, 23);
    contentPane.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_1);
    cbList.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_1);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_2 = new JCheckBox("IN");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_2.setBounds(177, 94, 72, 23);
    contentPane.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_2);
    cbList.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_2);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_3 = new JCheckBox("JP");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_3.setBounds(17, 133, 63, 23);
    contentPane.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_3);
    cbList.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_3);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_4 = new JCheckBox("FR");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_4.setBounds(104, 133, 63, 23);
    contentPane.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_4);
    cbList.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_4);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_5 = new JCheckBox("DE");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_5.setBounds(177, 133, 72, 23);
    contentPane.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_5);
    cbList.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_5);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_6 = new JCheckBox("ES");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_6.setBounds(17, 174, 63, 23);
    contentPane.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_6);
    cbList.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_6);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_7 = new JCheckBox("IT");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_7.setBounds(104, 174, 63, 23);
    contentPane.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_7);
    cbList.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_7);

    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_8 = new JCheckBox("CA");
    chckbxNewCheckBox_8.setBounds(177, 174, 72, 23);
    contentPane.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_8);
    cbList.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_8);
```

Alexeys comment got me thinking about checking wether or not any Checkboxes were selected, which might be useful to check at first.

```java
private boolean selectionWasMade()
{
    int selectedCounter = 0;

    for(JCheckBox checkbox : cbList)
    {
        if(checkbox.isSelected())
        {
            selectedCounter++;
        }
    }

    if(selectedCounter != 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now you simply check if this returns true and execute this loop:

```java
if(selectionWasMade())
{
    for(JCheckBox checkbox : cbList)
    {
        if(checkbox.isSelected())
        {
            aru.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys("SNS - Checkout Preflight - Desktop - " + checkbox.getText() + " - "+content);
        }
    }
}
else
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select from list");
}
```

Hope I could help, my answer should be all cleaned up and correct now after several edits!

Comment: In your example you will show the error message to the user as soon as it will enounter first unchecked check-box

Comment: I just noticed that too after reading your comment on OP lol! Will edit my bad.

Comment: It will heplful a lot i think. I will execute based on this and let see the results. Thanks @yur